# jQuery video hover optimising dynamic selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, caching

I'm working on something where the user hovers over a video to trigger it playing. When they hover over a different video, this new video starts playing and stops the others.

I'm using Vimeo and their [Froogaloop](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api) library ( not too relevant here, could also be video tags, mainly concerned with the caching of the selectors ).

This code works fine, but I know it's not as optimised as it should be, it uses multiple selectors each time the hover function is called which I don't want to do. Can I improve this code so that it doesn't do this? Or is it Ok to keep calling the jQuery selectors like this in modern browsers now?

[Here is a simplified working demo](https://jsbin.com/cevuzudeda/edit?html,js,output)

```
function hoverVid() {
  var frame = $(this).find('iframe');
  var player = $f(frame[0]);
  player.api('play');

  var vids = $('.vid-row iframe').not(frame);
  vids.each(function(index) {
    var frame = $(this);
    var player = $f(frame[0]);
    player.api('pause');
  });
}

$('.vid-row').hover(hoverVid);
```

Cheers :]

Comment: The only improvement I see is just to pause all video before playing the new hovered. [Here](https://jsbin.com/yoxucuceje/1/) you can see your jsbin updated

Comment: Cheers @GerardCuadras , so that update is just to make sure there is no overlap in the pause-play I assume?

Comment: exactly @00-BBB that way you will be sure that you don't pause the video that has to be played. But at terms of optimization will be the same. Also check that I've changed `var vids = $('.vid-row iframe').not(frame);`.

Comment: Ah yeah I see, here's my [updated bin](https://jsbin.com/raxuqasose/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I improved it a bit - As per @GerardCuadras comment, removed the need for using the .not() filter by simply pausing all the videos, then playing the desired one.

This allowed me to cache the list of iframes. I also optimised the selector to use an #id and .find().

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/qirofo/edit?html,js,output)

```
var vidz = $('#vidz').find('iframe');

function hoverVid(e){

  vidz.each(function( index ){
    var frame = $(this);
    var player = $f(frame[0]);
    player.api('pause');
  });

  var frame = $(this).find('iframe');
  var player = $f(frame[0]);
  player.api('play'); 
}

$('.vid-row').hover(hoverVid);
```